# Corel Draw X6 accident

Tags: corel-draw

I have such trouble. Or some problem with Corel Draw or with files. Do not open any single file. Says the file is corrupted. I'm using X6 with all updates. I'm working on a new computer with 8 GB of RAM and Windows 7. Many say that the X6 is better suited for Windows8. Can my preferences with Windows 7 to be the cause of the accident? I personally do not like Windows 8. Or now I'll be forced to use a product that does not like?
Are there any suggestions to ease my disappointment?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using windows 7 -- currently with X7, but before that for at least two years with X6.
X6 sometimes crashed frequently, but I found that the most frequent crashes could be prevented by regularly emptying the windows %temp% folder. You can either do that manually, preferably after a reboot, or use a program like cCleaner to do it. Others have also observed that crashes are more likely to happen if you allow too many fonts to be installed at the same time.

There is one other thing that I always do, which may help. **In control panel > system > advanced system settings > advanced > settings >** advanced go to the **virtual memory settings >****change** and turn off the "Automatically manage" option.

Further down, select **custom size.** At the bottom of the screen, note the recommended size and in the middle of the screen, set **at least** that value to the initial and maximum sizes.
 To be certain -- **the initial and maximum values must both be the same** and no less than the recommended value.

This prevents windows from constantly growing and shrinking the swap file, which I suspect has no real benefit and may cause unnecessary temporary disruption every time the size is changed.
Also are exists a third-part tools for recover corel draw files. For example   from here: [CorelDrawRecoveryToolbox](https://www.oemailrecovery.com/coreldraw_recovery.html)
It allow you to view content of corrupted .cdr file without Corel draw.

You can also find useful information on this site how to recover corel draw files
http://www.fixya.com/support/t25280540-corel_draw_x6_problems

Answer (score 0):

This question will be closed because it is a tech support one. But Ill give you some tips.

There is no way to know. So the first step is to copy some sample files and try to open them in another computer with Corel installed.

If the files are ok, see if the files are not generated by a newer version of Corel.

If both previous steps are ok, it is an instalation problem. Try to run install again and choose "repair".

Beyond that you need to contact tech support of Corel draw directly.

Comment: I tried to open them on another computer, in this program, but encountered the same problem.

Comment: But thanks for the response and recommendation.